# jquery dynamically changed property of the checkbox but not getting each checkbox value

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel-5, checkbox

Here is what I tried to do. I just did checked all items when 1 item is checked.But when all items checked checked property is not found.Do not able to understand whats doing wrong.

```
    <html>
    <td>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" rel="{{ $sq->id }}" class="select-multiple {{$qr- 
    >item_no}} select-items{{$j}}" value="{{$qr->item_no}}" name="state{{ 
    $sq->id }}">
    </label>
    </td>
    </html>


    var itemCode ='';
    $('.select-multiple').on('click',function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    itemCode = $(this).val();
    if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.'+itemCode).prop('checked', false);
    }else{
        $('.'+itemCode).prop('checked', true);
        $("input:checkbox[class="+itemCode+"]:checked").each(function() {
            alert(itemCode);
        });
    }
  });
```

Comment: 1.Add jquery library before script code.2.wrap you code inside `<script></script>`

Comment: Just cann't give the full code.Of course I have already done that. Thats not an issue here.

Comment: your question code is useless until you will provide relevant code (HTML+jquery). We can't check it.

Comment: I am sorry if there is not enough information but @B. Desai 's answer has worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class selector is incorrect for loop. change

```
$("input:checkbox[class="+itemCode+"]:checked").each(function() {
            alert(itemCode);
        });
```

To

```
$("."+itemCode+":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            alert(itemCode);
        });
```